# When using a jumphost, SSH asking if I want to continue

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, authentication

I am trying to connect to a remote host through a jumphost using SSH. For some reason, it is telling me that the authenticity of the jumphost can't be established even though I have specified StrictHostKeyChecking=no and UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

This is the SSH command that I am using and the output I see:

```
root@af23e0535685:/# ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -oHostkeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -caes256-cbc -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -J user@jumphost:12345 host
The authenticity of host '[jumphost]:12345 ([1.2.3.4]:12345)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:PmtXzdDfo+TrHhUgXWls8PeNh1XdHfTCEpEiT/ACT5I.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Eventually, I will be using this command as a Paramiko ProxyCommand string in Python, but first I need to disable this prompt.

SSH version is "OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019"

I am running Debian 10.7 in a Docker container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ssh` applies the options (`-oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` etc) to the final connection to `host`, but not the intermediate connection to `user@jumphost`. Generally, the best way to apply settings like this to the jumphost is to put them in your ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host jumphost
    Port 12345
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    [...etc...]
```

If you only want to use these option for that host *sometimes*, you can give that config an alternate name in the config files:

```
Host jumphost-nocheck
    Port 12345
    HostName jumphost
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    [...etc...]
```

If you're using this a lot, you can also add another `Host` entry for the final host that includes all of those options, and also `JumpHost jumphost`, and it'll be fully automated.

Or if the config file's not an option, you can [use a `ProxyCommand` option on the command line](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Old_Methods_of_Passing_Through_Jump_Hosts) (instead of `-J`), and specify the necessary options as part of that command:

```
ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 \
    -oHostkeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -caes256-cbc \
    -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@jumphost-p 12345" \
     host
```

Comment: Thank you... This cleared up the issue.  I can connect through the jump host to my host without any extra prompts now.